# Dynamically create variable and assign value to it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I have List of Objects
Using ng-repeat i am binding these objects to HTML elements.
in my ng-loop i have a button , when user will click on this button i want to show the next level HTML Elements.
Means , I have outer ng-repeat loop (for 1st level) and inner ng-repeat loop (for 2nd level).
For showing inner HTML elements e.g  tag i need to use ng-show.

But if i use a single variable all other's 2nd level elements are also visible.
I want only particular HTML to get visible.

How i can bind ng-show to variable and how i can set value to this variable.

Comment: Post some actual code and what you've tried - can't get much from just this description

Comment: Sorry tymeJV i was not having time to Edit my original office code and post it here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that what you want is to define an item-level variable inside `ng-repeat`.

You can set an item-level variable with `ng-init`. This variable will be created in the child scope created for each iteration of `ng-repeat`.

Then, you can toggle (or apply whatever logic) this variable with a button. Then, I suggest using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` to prevent generating DOM elements for items that user did not want to see.

```
<div ng-repeat="outerItem in outerList" ng-init="show = false">
   <button ng-click="show = !show">show/hide inner</button>
   <div ng-if="show" ng-repeat="innerItem in innerList">
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you New Dev for giving me good direction. i just instead of "show" i have created dynamic variable like this ng-init="this['obj_'+obj.item1]=false"

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to tell exactly what you mean based on your description, but you can bind ng-show to a function that passes in a name and then returns true or false based on that.

```
        <div ng-show="checkIfShow('dynamicName')">Something</div>


        $scope.checkIfShow = function(name) {
           // check name for whatever you are looking for to show/hide and return true/false
        };
```

You can easily create a map in JS where the 'name' passed in is the key and bind to that.